# What is the term in linguistics for when a word comes to have a new meaning over time?

Tags: terminology, linguistics

What is the term in linguistics for when a word comes to have a new meaning over time?

(Like the word 'wicked', which is commonly used to demonstrate this idea)

Comment: *Meaning migration*? *Sense shift*?

Comment: @user52882 this is not a service, it is just a collection of people who enjoy asking and answering questions, welcome aboard! Please remember to accept an answer if it answers your question. That's the way to show thanks.

Comment: Well, Stack Exchange is a service to humanity :)

Answer (score 16):

It is called [*semantic change*](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Semantic_change) (also semantic shift, semantic progression or semantic drift).

Comment: Thanks, I thought so but suspected there was a single word that fitted it better. This will suffice. Great response time and nice service this.

Comment: Is it still considered "semantic change" when the new meaning is additional, i.e. when the older meaning shows no signs of going away?

Comment: Is it still considered change if I put a million dollars in my bank account without taking any out?

Comment: @LarsH: **Semantic change** from Wikipedia: ...
Semantic change ... is the evolution of word usage — usually to the point that the modern meaning is radically different from the original usage. 
_Types of semantic change_: A number of classification schemes have been suggested for semantic change. _The most widely accepted scheme_ in the English-speaking academic world is from Bloomfield (1933): Narrowing: ... 
_However, the categorization of Blank (1998) has gained increasing acceptance:_ [2] Metaphor: Change based on similarity between concepts, e.g., mouse "rodent" → "computer device".