# Is there a word for when a change in usage orphans a definition?

Tags: single-word-requests, terminology

Is there a simple way to describe the phenomenon when the usage of a word or expression changes in such a way that it leaves the original concept without a word to describe it?

As usage evolves, sometimes the new meaning orphans an existing definition. For example, *cadence* is used when *schedule*, *period*, or *rhythm* is meant.

"We are on a weekly cadence for planning meetings" vs. "We are on a weekly schedule for planning meetings."

At some point, we will no longer have a word meaning "a sequence of notes or chords comprising the close of a musical phrase." There is no alternative word for this definition of *cadence.*

Another example: "Begging the question" is used all the time to mean "suggesting the question," rather than its original definition of the logical fallacy of assuming the conclusion in the premise.

Comment: I think your question is worth asking, but the examples could be improved. The fact that *cadence* now has another meaning (relating to schedules) does not mean that it has lost its original meaning.  In fact, it already had multiple meanings before management scientists adopted it. The fact that the contexts of those various uses are so different makes it unlikely that adopting the new one will orphan the old one.  A better example might be *terrific*, or *awesome*, which were once related to fright, but are now usually entirely positive descriptions.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [What is the term in linguistics when a word comes to have a new meaning over time, e.g 'wicked' is commonly used to demonstrate this](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/128902/what-is-the-term-in-linguistics-when-a-word-comes-to-have-a-new-meaning-over-tim)

Comment: *semantic drift*

Comment: If the new meaning gets rid of the old one it's called *semantic narrowing*.

Comment: *Literally* might be a better example, since its modern meaning fits the same contexts as the historical meaning, so that as the new meaning takes over the old one really can't be used any longer without causing confusion.

Comment: This might be a better question for [linguistics.se]

Comment: *At some point, we will no longer have a word meaning "a sequence of notes or chords comprising the close of a musical phrase."* This is extremely unlikely, because such musical transitions will still occur, and musicians will need a name to refer to them, so they will almost certainly keep using the word "cadence" (at least until some better word comes along, which might never happen).

Comment: This has happened with the word *chauvinist*, as *male chauvinism* has replaced the previous definition, and young people now don't know it.

Comment: Begging the question has a fancy Latin name, and chauvinism is similar to partisanship, jingoism, stanning, etc. But even if there are alternatives, words do sometimes do this over long periods, with the OED marking senses as obsolete.